# Как изменить кодовую страницу строки

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть файл в кодировке windows

```
6935205398208;Краска;52,15
6920702797104;Сметана;4,25
353891040181013;Сыр;12,86
U6LDU13B30001710;Молоко;7,85
```

Оригинал файла который читаю [Ссылка на файл](https://yadi.sk/i/v1tOp8x13GMHEW)

Код для чтения

```
// Get the File path from the Uri
                    String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);

                    // Alternatively, use FileUtils.getFile(Context, Uri)
                    if (path != null && FileUtils.isLocal(path)) {
                        File file = new File(path);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+file.getName());

                        //File sdFile = new File(file, file.getName());
                        try {
                            // открываем поток для чтения
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                            String str = "";
                            int i=0;
                            // читаем содержимое
                            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                createRecordProductInRealm(str);
                                i=i+1;

                                Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: *************** "+str);
                                String tmp = str;
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes("windows-1251"), "windows-1251");   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes("windows-1251"));   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes(), "KOI8-R");   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes(), "UTF-8");   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes(), "UTF-16");   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes(), "Cp1251");   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);
                                tmp = new String(str.getBytes(), "Cp866");   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: "+tmp);

                                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "Загружено "+i+" товаров", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Никак не могу получить русский текст, на фото результат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста с кодировкой, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено, надо изменять кодировку не строки, а файла

```
// открываем поток для чтения
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(
                                            new FileInputStream(file), Charset.forName("windows-1251")));
```